Nothing happens when transferring data to the database
I have a problem. I'm new to django. And so the error lies in the fact that nothing happens during the data transfer. The database is not being updated. I will be very grateful for your help!
this is code:
registration/urls.py:
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('/register', views.register, name='register'),
]

registration/views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import RegistrationForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


def register(request):  # Change function name to match the URL pattern
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            login(request, user)
            print(form)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
        return redirect('news')

    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form':form})

urls.py(In the project itself):
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    path('news/', include('news.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

register.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Регистрация</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Регистрация</h1>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'register' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.email }}
        {{ form.password1 }}
        {{ form.password2 }}
        <button type="submit">Зарегистрироваться</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

forms.py:
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['email'].label = 'Email address'
        self.fields['password1'].label = 'Password'
        self.fields['password2'].label = 'Confirm Password'

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'password1', 'password2')

I've tried a lot of YouTube videos and documentation, but still

What is the result of "print(form)"? Does it include the form values correctly?

No one outputs anything

Add else condition to your if form.is_valid. In your else condition do the same:
print(form) and/or print(form.errors). You will see the errors. It is probably a mismatch between your form fields expected and template.
